# Failed to Initialize backend EGL display in Android Emulator on Apache Server

Tags: android, android-emulator, web2py

We are developing a web-service to perform dynamic analysis of apps.
We have developed our scripts in python and tested our web-service using `web2py framework`.
But when we hosted our code on Apache server, a script to start the android emulator failed, displaying the message:

```
"Failed to Initialize backend EGL display"
```

But the same script runs without any errors from terminal or web2py server.

This problem is killing my days and now StackOverflow is my only hope.

Comment: Genymotion 2.3.7 Gives the same error.

Answer (score -2):

Failed to Initialize backend EGL display is actually not a programming error at all its the emulator error you are using.
try using genymotion.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, yes its emulator error. But Emulator started from the same script either from terminal or from web2py server, gets booted up without any errors. I need to use standard Android Emulator from analysis purpose, so cant shift to genymotion.

Comment: you welcome,try genymotion its the best emulator for android developer.